# Using CSS to put some DIVs over a picture (+explaining images)

Tags: css

  '.$row['titulo'].''.$contenido.time_since(strtotime($row['dt'])).'
  ');
      }
      ?>

The styles are in a separate file and they are:

```
.newsticker-jcarousellite { width:600px; }
.newsticker-jcarousellite ul li{ list-style:none; display:block; padding-bottom:1px; margin-bottom:5px; }
.newsticker-jcarousellite .thumbnail { float:left; width:50px; height:50px; }
.newsticker-jcarousellite .info { float:right; width:535px; }
.newsticker-jcarousellite .info span.cat { display: block; font-size:10px; color:#808080; }
```

All generates this:
[image]

But now, i need to add 3 litle div on the lower part of the profile picture all of them with a black (35% transparent) background where i can put some text, the result must look like this:
[image]

Im very new at css, and i realy dont have any idea how to do this, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete code (untested):

**HTML/PHP:**

```
<div id="newsticker-demo">    
    <div class="newsticker-jcarousellite">
<ul>
<?php
echo('<li>
<div class="thumbnail"><img src="'.$fotoperfil.'">
    <div class="txt">
        <span>t1</span>
        <span>t2</span>
        <span>t3</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="info"><a href="'.$linkpregunta.'">'.$row['titulo'].'</a><span class="cat">'.$contenido.time_since(strtotime($row['dt'])).'</span></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</li>');
}
?></ul></div></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.newsticker-jcarousellite { width:600px; }
.newsticker-jcarousellite ul li{ list-style:none; display:block; padding-bottom:1px; margin-bottom:5px; }
.newsticker-jcarousellite .thumbnail { float:left; width:50px; height:50px; position:relative /* <- new property */ }
.newsticker-jcarousellite .info { float:right; width:535px; }
.newsticker-jcarousellite .info span.cat { display: block; font-size:10px; color:#808080; }

/* new */
.newsticker-jcarousellite .thumbnail .txt { position:absolute; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; background:#000; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.35); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you add the CSS property `position: relative` the style of `.newsticker-jcarousellite ul li`, you could simply add another div inside that block, and set the style to be `position: absolute`, and set the top offset to be ~30-40px or so.
If you need to put multiple divs on top of the image, maybe it would be a better solution to make that image a `background-image`, as per the CSS property, and then use paddings to get most of the text to flow around it.

As it is, do you *need* to have multiple text items above it, rather than one block item containing multiple things of text?

Answer (score 1):

the solution is the attribute z-index,
the image has a lower z-index than the 3 divs with the text
you just have then to position them relative to the image or absolute

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```
.thumbnail { display:block; float:left; width:125px; height:125px; background:#666; position:relative }
.thumbnail-info { position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100% } /* info inside the thumbnail positioned absolute to the bottom */
.thumbnail .text1, .text2, .text3 { margin:0 2px } /* margin on the right and left */
.thumbnail .text1 { float:left; color:#fff; font-size:10px } /* floated text */
.thumbnail .text2 { float:left; color:#fff; font-size:10px }
.thumbnail .text3 { float:left; color:#fff; font-size:10px }

<div class="thumbnail"><img src="/image">
  <div class="thumbnail-info">
   <span class="text1">Date</span>
   <span class="text2">Time</span>
   <span class="text3">Hour</span> 
  </div>
  <!-- thumbnail info end -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the trasparency you can use:

```
.youInternalDivs="opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40);background-color:gray"
```

Firefox and Chrome use the property opacity:x for transparency, while IE uses filter:alpha(opacity=x).

You can also set an image as background for your smaller divs.